# Как вывести «Статьи» на главной странице WebAsyst

Tags: php, smarty

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста. На главной странице `index.html` нужно вывести блок/содержимое 
"/published/SC/html/scripts/templates/fronten/articles.frontend.list.tpl.html" статьи.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго дня. Шаблонизатор `smarty` - это серверный шаблонизатор. Т.е. через статический файл `index.html` этот шаблонизатор не заработает. Вам нужно либо что-то другое, либо вы чего-то не договариваете.

Comment: В webasyst обрабатываются файлы шаблона, а именно index.html

Comment: @Bomboos в smarty есть специальная функция в шаблоне [{include}][1],
выглядит примерно так:

    {include file="fronten/articles.frontend.list.tpl.html"}


 [1]: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include

Comment: @lampa, дело в том, что этот файл принимает в себя параметры конструктора. Если я его подключу на прямую к своему файлу, он не примет параметры и не выведет, что нужно.